# Labelling nodes in causes zooming glitch in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am new to d3js and am having an some issues with zooming.

After playing with some example code online I was able to make a timeline of just circles where the axis could zoom in and out. However, when I tried to add labels to these circles, the zooming feature either stops working OR the circles update their positions but the old circles never leave the timeline. Thus, I suspect my issue has something to do with the exit selection not recognizing the g elements for deletion (where I store my circle and label elements together).

After reading through the documentation and some selection tutorials I still cannot determine what is causing the issue. Please see the code below or the [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fh4x9hnu/):

```
    var ex_chart = example();

    var data = [];

   data.push({
      date: new Date(2016, 01, 07),
      event: "School"
   });
   data.push({
        date: new Date(2016, 01, 17),
            event: "Lunch"
   });
   data.push({
            date: new Date(2016, 01, 01),
           event: "Movies"
   });
  data.push({
           date: new Date(2016, 01, 30),
          event: "Birthday"
   });

    d3.select('#chart')
      .append("svg").attr("width", window.innerWidth).attr("height", window.innerHeight)
   .datum(data).call(ex_chart);

    function example() {
      var svg;
      var margin = {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10,
        right: 10
  };
  var width = 500;
  var height = 50;
  var xaxis = d3.svg.axis();
  var yaxis = d3.svg.axis();
  var xscale = d3.time.scale();
  var yscale = d3.scale.linear();



  var xyzoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(xscale)
    .on("zoom", draw);

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {
      svg = d3.select(this).selectAll('svg').data([data]);
      svg.enter().append('svg');
      var g = svg.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

      g.append("svg:rect")
        .attr("class", "border")
        .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", "none");

      g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")");


      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "scatter")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

      g
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("class", "zoom xy box")
        .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .call(xyzoom);


      var mindate = new Date(2016, 01, 1),
        maxdate = new Date(2016, 01, 31);
      xscale.domain([mindate, maxdate])
        .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);


      xaxis.scale(xscale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickPadding(10);

      svg.select('g.x.axis').call(xaxis);


      svg.select('g.y.axis').call(yaxis);

      draw();
    });

    return chart;
  }

  function update() {

    var gs = svg.select("g.scatter");

    var container = gs.selectAll("g")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      });


    var gnode = container.enter().append("g");


    gnode.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "points")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {

        return xscale(d.date);
      })
      .attr("cy", 10)
      .attr("r", 10);


    gnode.append("text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) {
        return xscale(d.date)
      })
      .attr("dy", 5)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.event[0]
      });

    container.exit().remove();
  }

  function zoom_update() {
    xyzoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(xscale)

    .on("zoom", draw);


    svg.select('rect.zoom.xy.box').call(xyzoom);

  }

  function draw() {
    update();
    zoom_update();
  };


  return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! the responsibility of updating the x coordinates should have been given to the update selection, but this functionality was not present in the posted code. Ex:

```
  container.selectAll("circle") .attr("cx", function(d) {

            return xscale(d.date);
```

was needed in the update function. Please let me know if a better solution exists